How can I enumerate Rust ndarray arrays in parallel?
How can I enumerate Rust ndarray arrays in parallel?
Currently I use:
depth.indexed_iter_mut().par_bridge()

I believe there is an API that does this, but I can only find par_iter and par_iter_mut, both of which I cannot call .enumerate() on.

What makes you believe that there is an API to do it? rayon and ndarray are unrelated crates, so there's no reason for such an API to exist. And your solution looks fine to me.

ndarray has a feature flag calls rayon, which indicates inter crate support. They are not unrelated crates in this aspect I think.

@FinnBear what does "efficiently" mean, in objective terms?

@TylerH It's not my word; the docs of par_bridge() say: "the resulting ParallelIterator can be less efficient than if you started with par_iter instead." Internally, this is because par_bridge() locks a Mutex to pull out items. When there are many items (such as cells in an ndarray) with very little work to do for each, this overhead becomes a bottleneck (as described later in the docs).

@FinnBear We're talking about the question here, not what the docs say. You put the word "efficient" in the question, so you need to clarify what you mean by that, in a way that doesn't conflict with OP's intent with their original question, which didn't speak of "efficiency" at all. Here, I'll make an edit that fixes OP's problems without changing what it is they're asking for.

@TylerH Thanks! I'm personally confused, though. If not performance/efficiency, why would OP want "proper" parallelism (as opposed to their already-correct workaround) in the first place?

@FinnBear As for the question OP did ask, I don't see any interest in performance/efficiency at all. This appears to simply be a "how to" question--they want to enumerate parallel arrays and don't know how. So simply providing a solution that works would qualify as an acceptable answer.

Enumerate returns one-dimensional usize indices, but an ndarray::Array may have multiple dimensions. While it is possible to sequentially iterate in row major order, the current implementation of ndarray doesn't allow that for parallel iteration. You need to pick an Axis to enumerate in parallel, such as Axis(0):
use ndarray::{array, Array2, Axis, parallel::prelude::*};

fn main() {
    let mut arr: Array2<f64> = array![[1., 2.], [3., 4.], [5., 6.]];
    arr.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)).into_par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, a)| {
        println!("{i} = {a:?}");
    });
}

If you want to process all individual cells, consider iterating some axis or axes sequentially inside a parallel iteration of the remaining axis:
use ndarray::{array, Array2, Axis, parallel::prelude::*};

fn main() {
    let mut arr: Array2<f64> = array![[1., 2.], [3., 4.], [5., 6.]];
    let stride = arr.len_of(Axis(1));
    arr.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)).into_par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, mut a)| {
        for (j, n) in a.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            let index = i * stride  + j;
            println!("{index} = {n}");
        }
    });
}


Is this just another workarond or the proper way to do the job? I read that what users do is assign rayon jobs and let the underlying rayon runtime decide for us how to split the jobs properly. This way we are manually splitting up the jobs, which seems does not conform to how the rayon crate is designed.

@Da1sypetals What do you mean by "proper", exactly? You want it to feel like it matches up with how rayon works in other cases? Or something else?
